# How to find Competitors using social media data

Tags: r

I am working on social media project in which I am trying to find the list of my competitor using my social media data. For example, suppose Nokia is our client. He registered his facebook account into our platform and provide following details such as he is working on Mobile and electronic category and its head office is in US. So based on these details I want to find who are may be his customers.

Right now I start with facebook and generate all the required token and keys also fetch some facebook page data using the `getPage()` and `searchPage()` function in Rfacebook package in R.

How can I find the name of competitors from this data?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is maybe use Twitter instead of Facebook, and then aggregate the list of twitter handles mentioned in the tweets addressed to the brand.

For example, customers generally mention a brand along with its competitors when they are posting an issue on the twitter page of a brand. A customer dissatisfied with Nokia will also mention other smartphone companies like Apple and Samsung in its tweets, and when you aggregate all the twitter handles mentioned in Nokia tweets, smartphone companies will feature at the top.

R has a twitteR package which makes it fairly easy to pull tweets addressed to a twitter handle.